# Log4Net File Parameters

Tags: c#, file, log4net

This is somewhat two questions in one, both related to log4net.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
      <encoding value="utf-8"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <datePattern value=".MM-dd-yyyy"/>
      <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I have this configuration and what I want to achieve is so that I always have ONLY one log file that is max of 10 MB.

The problem that I'm getting is it creates a new file for each day (I thought preserve file of should fix it) and when I leave it for too long (accidently left it overnight), I came back to a file that is 6 GB big (which I thought maximumFileSize should handle).

Am I assuming too much of log4net or did I not set up the logger properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify

```
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
```

and

```
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="1"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
```

**maxSizeRollBackups = number of log files**

maximumFileSize = max size for one log file

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify

```
<RollingStyle value="Composite" />
<!-- change file depending date and length of the log file -->
```

Or

```
<RollingStyle value="Size" />
<!-- change file depending length of the log file -->
```

Instead of `Date`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `<rollingStyle value="Date"/>`

It should be

```
<rollingStyle value="Size"/>
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html RollingFileAppender